# How write good round_double function in c++?

Tags: c++, c, double, rounding

I'm trying to write good round_double function which will round double in specified precision:

1.

```
double round_double(double num, int prec)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < abs(prec); ++i)
        if(prec > 0)
            num *= 10.0;
        else
            num /= 10.0;
    double result = (long long)floor(num + 0.5);
    for (int i = 0; i < abs(prec); ++i)
        if(prec > 0)
            result /= 10.0;
        else
            result *= 10.0;
    return result;
}
```

2.

```
double round_double(double num, int prec)
{
    double tmp = pow(10.0, prec);
    double result = (long long)floor(num * tmp + 0.5);
    result /= tmp;
    return result;
}
```

This functions do what I wan't but they are, in my opinion, not good enough. Because starting from precision = 13 - 14, they returning bad results.

The cause I'm sure that there is possible to write good double_round is that just printing the number via `cout` in specified precision (say 18) is prints better result than result of my function.

For example this part of code:

```
int prec = 18;
double num = 10.123456789987654321;
cout << setiosflags(ios::showpoint | ios::fixed)
<< setprecision(prec) << "round_double(" << num << ", " 
<< prec << ") = " << round_double(num, prec) << endl;
```

Will print `round_double(10.123456789987655000, 18) = -9.223372036854776500` for first `round_double` and `round_double(10.123456789987655000, 18) = -9.223372036854776500`for second one.

How write good round_double function in c++? Or there is already exists?

Comment: double has a decimal precision of 15 digits. you cannot get precise values beyond that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't cast to `long long` that is forcing a conversion to an integer with limited range, beyond what 10^13 requires (well 19 for 64-bit with no whole number part).  Just calling `floor` should be enough.

```
double round_double(double num, int prec)
{
    double tmp = pow(10.0, prec);
    double result = floor(num * tmp + 0.5);
    result /= tmp;
    return result;
}
```

---

Note that Mike is also correct, you have a limited range you can represent just in double itself. It isn't so great if you need clean decimal responses. But the `long long` is the cause of your totally wacky numbers.

Comment: Thank you for pointing on this. But in this case also starting from 18 - 19 results are different.

Comment: You have to consider the whole number part of the number you are rounding. If all 10^19 is used for the fractional rounding there is no space to store the whole number. So `10.123` probably starts failing at around 17 precision.

Comment: But again, as what Mike says, double doesn't even have this high of precision, so even fixing the `long long` won't help at this point.  If you have a `long double` it might help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the floating-point representation. A binary representation cannot represent all decimal numbers exactly, and only has a finite precision.

`double` usually means a 64-bit binary representation as specified by IEEE754, with a 52-bit fractional part. This gives a precision of approximately 16 decimal digits.

If you need more precision than that, then the best option is probably to use an arbitrary-precision arithmetic library such as [GMP](http://gmplib.or). Your compiler may or may not offer a `long double` type with a higher precision than `double`.

**EDIT**: sorry, I didn't notice that you're getting completely incorrect results. As another answer says, this is due to the conversion to `long long` overflowing.

Comment: I don't wan't use GMP or other libraries that works with big decimals. I just wan't that result of precisioned cout and result of my function was the same.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question and thought you were asking why you don't get 18 digits of precision.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to round based on binary-digits of precision.  Sample implementation below - not sure if it's useful to you, but since you got me playing I thought I'd throw it out there.

Notes:

- this uses the ieee754.h header common on Linux systems: it could easily be ported to Windows, but this is undeniably bit hackery and whether it's appropriate in any given production code is a case-by-case call.
- you could approximate some decimal near-equivalent, e.g. multiply the desired decimal precision by 10 and divide by 3 (based on 2^10 ~= 10^3).

The input number (10.1234...) with 1 bit of precision is 8; with 2 it's 10 etc..

Separately, IMHO decimal rounding is best done at output time, or when using a decimal-capable representation (e.g. storing an `int` mantissa and power-of-10 exponent).

```
#include <ieee754.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

double round_double(double d, int precision)
{
    ieee754_double* p = reinterpret_cast<ieee754_double*>(&d);
    std::cout << "mantissa  0:" << std::hex << p->ieee.mantissa0
        << ", 1:" << p->ieee.mantissa1 << '\n';
    unsigned mask0 = precision < 20 ? 0x000FFFFF << (20 - precision) :
                                      0x000FFFFF;
    unsigned mask1 = precision <  20 ? 0 :
                     precision == 53 ? 0xFFFFFFFF :
                                       0xFFFFFFFE << (32 + 20 - precision);
    std::cout << "masks     0:" << mask0 << ", 1: " << mask1 << '\n';
    p->ieee.mantissa0 &= mask0;
    p->ieee.mantissa1 &= mask1;
    std::cout << "mantissa' 0:" << p->ieee.mantissa0
        << ", 1:" << p->ieee.mantissa1 << '\n';
    return d;
}

int main()
{
    double num = 10.123456789987654321;

    for (int prec = 1; prec <= 53; ++prec)
        std::cout << std::setiosflags(std::ios::showpoint | std::ios::fixed)
            << std::setprecision(60)
            << "round_double(" << num << ", "  << prec << ") = "
            << round_double(num, prec) << std::endl;
}
```

Output...

```
mantissa  0:43f35, 1:ba76eea7
masks     0:fff80000, 1: 0
mantissa' 0:0, 1:0
round_double(10.123456789987654858009591407608240842819213867187500000000000, 1) = 8.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
mantissa  0:43f35, 1:ba76eea7
masks     0:fffc0000, 1: 0
mantissa' 0:40000, 1:0
round_double(10.123456789987654858009591407608240842819213867187500000000000, 2) = 10.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
mantissa  0:43f35, 1:ba76eea7
masks     0:fffe0000, 1: 0
mantissa' 0:40000, 1:0
round_double(10.123456789987654858009591407608240842819213867187500000000000, 3) = 10.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
mantissa  0:43f35, 1:ba76eea7
masks     0:ffff0000, 1: 0
mantissa' 0:40000, 1:0
round_double(10.123456789987654858009591407608240842819213867187500000000000, 4) = 10.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
mantissa  0:43f35, 1:ba76eea7
masks     0:ffff8000, 1: 0
mantissa' 0:40000, 1:0
round_double(10.123456789987654858009591407608240842819213867187500000000000, 5) = 10.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
mantissa  0:43f35, 1:ba76eea7
masks     0:ffffc000, 1: 0
mantissa' 0:40000, 1:0
round_double(10.123456789987654858009591407608240842819213867187500000000000, 6) = 10.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
mantissa  0:43f35, 1:ba76eea7
masks     0:ffffe000, 1: 0
mantissa' 0:42000, 1:0
round_double(10.123456789987654858009591407608240842819213867187500000000000, 7) = 10.062500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
mantissa  0:43f35, 1:ba76eea7
masks     0:fffff000, 1: 0
mantissa' 0:43000, 1:0
round_double(10.123456789987654858009591407608240842819213867187500000000000, 8) = 10.093750000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
mantissa  0:43f35, 1:ba76eea7
masks     0:7ffff800, 1: 0
mantissa' 0:43800, 1:0
round_double(10.123456789987654858009591407608240842819213867187500000000000, 9) = 10.109375000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
mantissa  0:43f35, 1:ba76eea7
masks     0:3ffffc00, 1: 0
mantissa' 0:43c00, 1:0
round_double(10.123456789987654858009591407608240842819213867187500000000000, a) = 10.117187500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
mantissa  0:43f35, 1:ba76eea7
masks     0:1ffffe00, 1: 0
mantissa' 0:43e00, 1:0
round_double(10.123456789987654858009591407608240842819213867187500000000000, b) = 10.121093750000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
mantissa  0:43f35, 1:ba76eea7
masks     0:fffff00, 1: 0
mantissa' 0:43f00, 1:0
round_double(10.123456789987654858009591407608240842819213867187500000000000, c) = 10.123046875000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

etc....
```